# Simple way to get Twitter users home feed

Tags: php, javascript, twitter, twitter-oauth

Does anyone know a good way to, using oAuth, retrieve a users home feed (using PHP or JavaScript)? I've been searching the web (Google, YouTube and the Twitter website), but have not yet found a simple tutorial like developers.facebook.com has.

If you know of a good tutorial, or you have written some code that works, I'd be glad to see it. I would prefer the entire process, from authorizing a user to displaying their feed, but anything is better than what I have now.

Hoping for answers!

Answer (score 1):

OAuth is method for authentication, you should use REST API provided by Twitter.

Please check this: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1 (statuses/user_timeline)

**Edit:**

https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

Please check "Extended flow using example code" section, there's everything you want to know.

Just one note, if you have long-live access token (from your app dashboard, see oauth tab), you just pass token and token secret as third and fourth parameter when you create new instance of TwitterOAuth class, like this:

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN,
OAUTH_SECRET);
```

Comment: Yes I know, but as I explained in my question, I want the entire process. That includes oAuth for authenticating a user, and then displaying their feed.